# Pagination Standards

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of a defined standard for Pagination?  We have a consultant company that buildt a website for us and part of the site has a list of items that uses pagination.  They have a pretty standard pagination layout consisting of two buttons on either side of a list of numbers (links).

```
[<<]  [<]   1   2   3   4   5   [>]  [>>]
```

The buttons [<] and [>] move you through the pages, either back on or forward one.  THe numbers are all direct links to the pages.

The problem I have is with the buttons with the double 'arrows'.  I think these should take you to the First or Last page.  Everyone here agrees with that and expect it to work that way.  However, the company that has designed the site has those buttons jumping 10 pages forward or backwards.  I"ve never seen this done like this, and so the expected behavior isn't what myself and other users are expecting.  This site just went live last night and we've already had 3 users report this functionality as a bug.

Is there a set of standards I can use for this to show the consultants? They don't want to change this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree with the below two posters, but I wanted to add that when I do a first/last button using characters I would usually do them using the pipe to show the "end" (e.g. [|<] or [|<<])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with pagination standards is the best solution really depends on:

- what it being paginated
- the size of the result set
- the performance and technical feasibility of moving through the result set

In your specific case, I would not expect a double arrow to move 10. This could be more useful than first/last, but the arbitrary 10 value should be displayed to the user in some way.

Here are some UI pagination examples:

- [Pagination Gallery: Examples And Good Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/16/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap Pagination](http://cssdeck.com/item/271/twitter-bootstrap-pagination-and-pager)
- [Yahoo Search Pagination](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/navigation/pagination/search.html)

Comment: Thanks James.  I agree with everything you've said, and so does everyone I work with.  I'm going to tell the guys designing this thing to at least give us a tool tip telling us we're only are navigating 10 items instead of moving to the first or last.

Comment: Awesome, Jeff. Good luck with the new site.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of anything like *standards* but I have always coded it the way you describe.  I could see forward 10 being useful if you had a relatively large number of pages but annoying for an extremely large number.  However, if you have that many pages, users are unlikely to page through the data anyway.  Searching is whats needed in that case.  Anyway, a consultant telling you that your are wrong seems like you should be looking for a new consultant.  They may disagree (and i could see their side of the argument) but you should have the final say...

Comment: I would agree. This consultant company seems to think they're way is always right. We've had other issues with them, like the Log Out button doesn't log you out if you checked the Remember Me check box when logging in.  If you do, you're logged in until you clear your cookies, because the one they created never expires.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I that the buttons to the far left and far right should move to the first and last pages, respectively. However, I also think that the company that made it used the correct behavior considering they are using double arrows. To me, the double arrow indicates that it does the same thing as the single arrow, but *more*. In other words, I think it makes sense that double arrows move 10 pages to the left or right since the single arrows move 1 page to the left or right.

Basically:

- I **agree** with the behavior **with respect to the symbols used**.
- I **don't agree** with the **choice of symbols**. In most cases, I think a single arrow + vertical line ( l< and >l ) would be more clear, but that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for a pagination control I built recently with the following benefits:

- First and Last page numbers always visible (no need for [<<] or [>>] buttons)
- Clicking the [...] allows quick jump to any page
- No words to localize (next, prev, first, last buttons aren't
  needed because the control is clear)
- No dependencies (jQuery not required)

Run the code snippet below and let me know what you think.

```js
var Pagination = {
  code: '',

  Extend: function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    Pagination.size = data.size || 300;
    Pagination.page = data.page || 1;
    Pagination.step = data.step || 3;
  },

  Add: function(s, f) {
    for (var i = s; i < f; i++) {
      Pagination.code += '<a>' + i + '</a>';
    }
  },

  Last: function() {
    Pagination.code += '<i>...</i><a>' + Pagination.size + '</a>';
  },

  First: function() {
    Pagination.code += '<a>1</a><i>...</i>';
  },


  Click: function() {
    Pagination.page = +this.innerHTML;
    Pagination.Start();
  },

  Prev: function() {
    Pagination.page--;
    if (Pagination.page < 1) {
      Pagination.page = 1;
    }
    Pagination.Start();
  },

  Next: function() {
    Pagination.page++;
    if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size) {
      Pagination.page = Pagination.size;
    }
    Pagination.Start();
  },

  TypePage: function() {
    Pagination.code = '<input onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);this.focus();" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.blur(); }" value="' + Pagination.page + '" /> &nbsp; / &nbsp; ' + Pagination.size;
    Pagination.Finish();
    var v = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    v.click();
    v.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {

      var p = parseInt(this.value);

      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(p)) && isFinite(p)) {
        if (p > Pagination.size) {
          p = Pagination.size;
        } else if (p < 1) {
          p = 1;
        }
      } else {
        p = Pagination.page;
      }

      Pagination.Init(document.getElementById('pagination'), {
        size: Pagination.size,
        page: p,
        step: Pagination.step
      });
    }, false);
  },


  Bind: function() {
    var a = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (+a[i].innerHTML === Pagination.page) a[i].className = 'current';
      a[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Click, false);
    }
    var d = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('i');
    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      d[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.TypePage, false);
    }
  },

  Finish: function() {
    Pagination.e.innerHTML = Pagination.code;
    Pagination.code = '';
    Pagination.Bind();
  },

  Start: function() {
    if (Pagination.size < Pagination.step * 2 + 6) {
      Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.size + 1);
    } else if (Pagination.page < Pagination.step * 2 + 1) {
      Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.step * 2 + 4);
      Pagination.Last();
    } else if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2) {
      Pagination.First();
      Pagination.Add(Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2 - 2, Pagination.size + 1);
    } else {
      Pagination.First();
      Pagination.Add(Pagination.page - Pagination.step, Pagination.page + Pagination.step + 1);
      Pagination.Last();
    }
    Pagination.Finish();
  },


  Buttons: function(e) {
    var nav = e.getElementsByTagName('a');
    nav[0].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Prev, false);
    nav[1].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Next, false);
  },

  Create: function(e) {
    var html = [
      '<a>&#9668;</a>', // previous button
      '<span></span>', // pagination container
      '<a>&#9658;</a>' // next button
    ];
    e.innerHTML = html.join('');
    Pagination.e = e.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    Pagination.Buttons(e);
  },

  Init: function(e, data) {
    Pagination.Extend(data);
    Pagination.Create(e);
    Pagination.Start();
  }
};

var init = function() {
  Pagination.Init(document.getElementById('pagination'), {
    size: 30, // pages size
    page: 1, // selected page
    step: 2 // pages before and after current
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1px 2px 4px 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #7D7D7D;
}
#pagination a,
#pagination i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 22px;
  color: #7D7D7D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#pagination a {
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pagination a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
#pagination i {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pagination i:hover {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pagination input {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #7D7D7D;
  text-align: right;
}
#pagination a.current {
  border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

Comment: sometimes clicking the ellipse makes the stack overflow page jump so try the same example here  --  http://codepen.io/run-time/full/raVGMp/